# Having same information on several devices

Tags: ipad

I have several ipads that I would like to be identical in terms of apps, music etc. Once I take the time to put on the appropriate apps, sort into folders etc then I would like that exact same configuration on the other two iPads. Is this possible? Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to sync data within the Apps, that will vary from app to app.  Look for iCloud support there.

If you are looking to have the same deployed content on each, look into [iPad Configurator](http://help.apple.com/configurator/mac/1.2/), which supports mirrored configurations.